# Reading and Transforming .pdf, .docx and .xls files

Tags: java, linux, excel, pdf

I have several files (.docx, .pdf...). Now I want to have features of this files, like counting their pages and transforming, as example, pdf to word and vice-versa. My Java program is running on Glassfish. I also have to run my program on Windows and Linux.

I've found [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library.

Pros: Does for Windows and Linux. Good documentation. Free.
Cons: Too much libraries to import. Don't know how fast or slow it is.

I know there also other libraries like aspose.

So, my question is: should I use Apache POI, or it is any other free library which could be the best one for me?

Answer (score 1):

Apache fop for transformations
    https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/
together with Apache poi 
    https://poi.apache.org
is a good combination